# Material Date Picker Difference Format on Difference Device

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

I need a help.
I'm working with date picker material.io.
And I get different format while installed the APK on difference device.
I figure out the problem is about language device setting.
Maybe someone here has the same problem like me? How to fix this problem?

Here's my date picker code :

```
    private val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().build()

    with(datePicker) {
        addOnCancelListener { datePicker.dismiss() }
        addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
            val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy")
            datePickerValue = LocalDate.parse(datePicker.headerText, formatter)
            binding.rowInputSearchDob.edtDob.setText(datePickerValue withFormat getString(R.string.date_format_d_MMM_yyyy))
        }
    }
```

Thanks before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date formatter and parser will be using the format and language settings of the device.. the "default" locale.
To override this you need to specify the locale. Probably by using ".withLocale" see [withLocale docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter#withLocale(java.util.Locale))